# ASP.NET-Core MVC6 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<..>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am getting a list of menuItems - an object from a service asynchronous method that returns...

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<MyNav.Models.Menu.MenuItem>>
```

The code that is calling it is:

```
var MainHeadings = _menuService.GetListByParentId(0)>;
foreach (var item in MainHeadings)
{
    ...
}
```

The error is on MainHeadings in the "foreach" and the error is:

> Error  CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<MyNav.Models.Menu.MenuItem>>' because 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<MyNav.Models.Menu.MenuItem>>' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'    MyNav.DNX 4.5.1, MyNav.DNX Core 5.0 C:\Users\simon\DEV\MyNav\src\MyNav\TagHelpers\Menu\DisplayAllMenuItems.cs   50  Active

The class calling the _menuService is a custom TagHelper and I did try and change the tagHelper to async eg

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
}
```

but the result did not render correctly.

Is there a way of fixing this as it worked when the service method was synchronous...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK solved this.  I believe the service needed to complete before continuing. By putting "await" before the call to _menuService it worked correctly.

```
          var MainHeadings = await _menuService.GetListByParentId(0);

        foreach (var item in MainHeadings)
        {
            if (item.Header)
            {
                contentSb.Append(await _menuService.ManageHeader(item, indent));
            }
            else
            {
                contentSb.Append(_menuService.ReturnSimpleAnchor(item, indent));
            }
        }
```

I placed the await on the line:

```
                contentSb.Append(await _menuService.ManageHeader(item, indent));
```

and it worked. That's a call to an async method.